Migrate a Windows 11 VMware guest to KVM/Qemu?
I have a Windows 11 guest that runs in VMware Workstation on a NixOS host.
It has TPM 2.0 and UEFI boot and encryption and all the standard hardware requirements of Windows 11.
I would prefer to run it in KVM/Qemu so I don't have to worry about kernel compatibility.
Currently I am using the 6.6 LTS kernel, because 6.9 isn't compiling right with VMware (or with VirtualBox, for that matter) on my NixOS host, and the 6.8 kernel is already EOL.
Can I convert this VM to qcow2 format and run it in Virt-Manager?
What would be the best way to do that, and what are the caveats? Will it degrade performance?

You should be able to convert your Workstation VM to qcow2 and run it in KVM. That's exactly what I did with my VMs for the same reason (Workstation compilation issues with every kernel update). I was converting Linux VMs though. KVM supports TPM and Windows 11. Might help: https://sysguides.com/install-a-windows-11-virtual-machine-on-kvm#10-110-enable-trusted-platform-module-tpm
As for conversion, qemu-img should do the job. https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html
StarWind V2V can do that as well. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter

My virtual disk is encrypted. It's a requirement now for new installations of Windows 11. Does KVM support that feature?
